# Is it possible to define the pwd for an external command runs in without changing VIM's pwd?

Tags: path

Im experiencing some problems running a command that reports paths based on the $PWD.

To correctly parse its output I need it to run from a different directory, however, I would rather not have to `cd` into that path in the current `vim` instance.

Is this possible?

Or is there a way to do this which doesn't manipulate the working directory history?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You can run the command in a sub-shell (assuming that you're running in Unix and not Windows) and include a `cd` command at the start of the sub-shell. For example,

```
:!(cd /usr/local; ls)
```

Or even simpler,

```
:!cd /usr/local; ls
```

Comment: I've come to prefer `:!cd path && command` (or `system('cd path &&...`, or `job_start`). This way if the path isn't accessible (whatever the reason), I got rejected.